# Is a business studies A Level valued by Employers?

Tags: applications, united-kingdom, employer, qualification

I've just started Year 12 and I've started out on Computer Science, English Literature and Business Studies. I like the two former subjects, but Business Studies is kind of one I've fell into because nothing else I want to do fits in the option blocks.

Therefore, my question is is business studies a valued A Level for employers? I don't intend to pursue it further than A Level and I'm looking to work in technology of some kind and aim to work towards being self-employed. Right now the career I'm looking at getting into is the Film visual effects industry, hence why I'm doing Computer Science.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65284/discussion-on-question-by-charlie-is-a-business-studies-a-level-valued-by-employ).

Answer (score 2):

Business Studies has always been a bit of a placeholder in the UK - it's a course college/sixth form students make to turn their two classes/grades into three.

On the other hand, if you get a university degree, pretty much no one will care about your A-level. But you have to get that degree. For what you want to do, you will almost certainly need Maths (particularly Applied Maths) - from what I recall of A level computer science, it is not going to cover what you will need for film visual effects.

Comment: visual effects is very much a skills based career rather than qualification based. Therefore the main thing they will look at is your portfolio; your qualifications will be there simply to support those skills. I'm developing my practical skills with visual effects in my spare time and building up a portfolio

Comment: I don't intend to do a Uni degree as of right now

Comment: Hmm... Have you spoken to a careers advisor or sometimes in the industry about how to get to do what you want. Visual effects is very software driven and I'd be surprised you can break into it without a bachelors degree

Comment: I don't really know many people involved in the industry to be honest, nothing more than people I've spoken to on the internet a few times. Its true that if I got a bachelor's degree I would be in an easier position, but it is possible to enter the career with a strong portfolio and also hopefully by the time I'm applying for things, a few small projects under my belt. Visual effects artists don't really pop up very often but I'm hoping to get a bit more involved with networking and the like and hopefully make a few contacts

Comment: Get the portfolio AND the degree - then you'll be a start hire - plus,  some universities can help with links into the industry. Can't remember exactly, but there's a couple of places near London that link in with the film studios like Pinewood.

Comment: if there were any university courses that were appealing, I would do them but I've looking and can't find much

Comment: There's not much of a demand for CGI courses